# How do I make Python's turtle screen recognize a right click?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I know that turtle.onscreenclick() defaults to btn=1, which is a left click, but what is the value for the other mousebuttons? I've tried to use turtle.onscreenclick(fun, 2), (fun, "2"), and several other combinations but none of them have worked. Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: `turtle.onscreenclick(fun, 2)` should work for a right click. Can you confirm fun does something? Are you running this in a console?

Comment: On my system, the `turtle` module treats the middle mouse button as button 2 and the right mouse button as button 3.